# Drawing canvas for mobile webpages with sketch.js resets ontouch

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, html5-canvas

I am using the `sketch.js` plugin for drawing on HTML5 canvas. While it works fine on desktop computers it seems to have some issues on mobile browsers.

**The problem is** that if I draw 2 different shapes, the canvas will reset to blank as soon as I touch it.

Just to be completly clear I will make and **example**: drawing the number '12' will first draw '1' and then when I start drawing '2' the canvas will clear and only keep the number '2'...

```
<!-- CANVAS -->
<canvas id="canvas1" style="width:100%; background:white; height:150px;"></canvas>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(function () {
                                $('#canvas1').sketch();
                            });                                               
                        </script>
```

This is it. I am wondering if there is some workaround to keep the history of the various drawings. I am open to any suggestion or to know if you have found a similar problem.

Answer (score 11):

To actually fix this bug, you need to change a few different lines of code.  The plugin is checking during each event if the user is using a desktop (mousedown, mousemove, mouseleave, mouseup) or a mobile (touchstart, touchend, touchcancel).  To determine the mouse/finger position to draw the next point, jQuery's `e.pageX` is being called.  This is directly defined in mobile, so the plugin is checking for mobile and if mobile is detected, saving the user's finger position defined by `e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageX`.  The problem comes from touchend or touchcancel because `e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0]` is not defined for these two events, so `e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageX` returns an error and the entire canvas is redrawn.  To fix this, you need to edit 2 lines of code around line 100/101.

Replace

```
e.pageX = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageX;
e.pageY = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageY;
```

With

```
if (e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0] !== undefined && e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageX!==undefined){
    e.pageX = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageX;
}
if (e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0] !== undefined &&e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageY){
    e.pageY = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageY;
}
```

See the answer below for more details.

[Sketch.js pageX undefined error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311073/sketch-js-pagex-undefined-error/22976319#22976319)

Answer (score 0):

See the workaround posted by leonth here:  https://github.com/intridea/sketch.js/issues/1

I made a jsFiddle with the workaround and it now works for me on mobile devices:http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/4hfkb/5/

```
switch (e.type) {
    case 'mousedown':
    case 'touchstart':          
      if (this.painting) {    //add
        this.stopPainting();  //add
      }                       //add
      this.startPainting();
      break;
...
```