# Sketch.js pageX undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, html5-canvas

I am using sketch.js by intridea in my phonegap application.It works allright with the modification

```
 case 'touchstart':
            if (this.painting) {//add
                this.stopPainting();
                //add
            }//add
            this.startPainting();
            break;
```

by adding the above lines to the code.But I am getting a pageX undefined error which is crashing my app.

```
01-23 19:53:59.342: E/Web Console(31932): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageX' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/js/external_libs/sketch.js:107
```

How to overcome this issue,any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Did you have any success using sketch.js in Phonegap? I'm trying to use it myself and it works but when you draw it clears the previously drawn line every time, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: @RickCurran : None unfortunately.I end up using jqscribble.js,which did the trick.

Comment: Thanks, I also switched to another library but used Fabric.js instead @Sumodh Nair

Comment: @RickCurran : Great :)

Answer (score 10):

It seems as if everyone has swtiched over to jqscribbel.js, but to directly answer this question with sketch.js, you need to check if `e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0]` is defined.  I haven't dug into sketch.js too much yet, but it seems that when a touchup event is triggered, `e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0]` is no longer defined, so trying to find `.pageX` of undefined gives an error.  This error causes the entire canvas to be re-drawn, so you cannot draw more than 1 sketch on the canvas.  To fix this error, simply add find the following two lines of code (around line 100/101):

```
e.pageX = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageX;
e.pageY = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageY;
```

and replace with

```
if (e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0] !== undefined && e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageX !== undefined){
    e.pageX = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageX;
}
if (e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0] !== undefined && e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageY !==undefined){
    e.pageY = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageY;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, `targetTouches[0]` is the solution for me on iOS, works with `clientX` as well.